# scanned packages

Tags: playorm

I have on my Eclipse workspace 2 projects:

1. playOrm (it's generated a jar file)
2. MyOwnProject ( I use the jar file generated above to use playOrm like ORM to Cassandra on MyOwnProject )

My question:

How can I, for my classes defined on MyOwnProject, use the same benefits of the User class defined on `com.alvazan.test.db` sample? When I execute a class located at MyOwnProject, playOrm creates it on my keyspace, and also manages the insert (`NoSqlEntityManager.put()` ) or query ( `@NoSqlQuery` )

I put those annotations on my classes but when I execute them the error message appears:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity type=com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.User was not scanned and added to meta information on startup.  It is either missing @NoSqlEntity annotation or it was not in list of scanned packages
```

I tried defining my classes with a `@NoSqlEntity` annotation but it's still not working.

Comment: just checking back...you marked the answer as helpful but not correct.  Does this mean you still did not get it to work?  Let me know if you don't have it working and what the current error is.  NOTE: I will be adding documentation on how to read the logs and what they mean and start and FAQ as well for common errors like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing the class nosql.Persistence.class in your jar file or folder?

If so, create a nosql.Persistence.java file.

PlayOrm scans all jars and folders on the classpath for nosql.Persistence and ONLY scans jars and folders with that file.

Why don't we use persistence.xml like JPA?

Because LOTS of frameworks and IDE's screw persistence.xml by only copying class files so we use a class file to be compatible with more frameworks.  ie. like playframework.org which is a real-time development framework(NO need to reboot server when you change stuff as all our classes are rescanned but we need a class file to pull that trick off)

If you haven't tried playframework.org, give it a spin....it is fast for developer productivity.

later,
Dean

Comment: I am having similar issue but I do have nosql.Persistence.java and I even moved the domain class to the "nosql" package, just in case.
I am using Grails app. Other examples, outside Grails work fine for me.